# Why does the OLS estimator simplify as follows for the single regressor case?

Tags: estimation, least-squares, multiple-regression, covariance-matrix

I was reading in "A Guide to Econometrics" that given $Y = X \beta + \epsilon$, the variance covariance matrix of $\beta^\text{OLS}$ is given by $\sigma^2 (X' X)^{-1}$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the error term...

it then says that in the case of a single regressor $y = \beta_1 + \beta_2 x$, that this simplifies to $\sigma^2 / \sum(x-\bar{x})^2$. I don't quite see this. Isn't the matrix $X$ in this case still a two by two matrix? Namely:

$$
X =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & x_1 \\\
1 & x_2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

How are we getting something like $\sum(x-\bar{x})^2$ ?

Comment: Clearly the book was talking about the variance of the slope, i.e. $\beta_2$. The covariance of $(\beta_1,\beta_2)$ is still $2\times 2$ matrix as Charlie demonstrated.

Comment: Also $X$ is usually $n\times k$ matrix, with $n$ being number of observations, $k$ being the number of right hand side variables including the constant. In your case $k=2$. The matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$ is then usualy $k\times k$ matrix, in your case $2\times 2$.

Answer (score 6):

Multiply $X^\prime X$:
$$\begin{align*} \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1^\prime 1 & 1^\prime x \\ x^\prime 1 & x^\prime x \end{array} \right] \end{align*}$$
Take the inverse ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_2.C3.972_matrices)):
$$\begin{align*} \frac{1}{Nx^\prime x - (1^\prime x)^2}\left[ \begin{array}{cc} x^\prime x & -1^\prime x \\ -1^\prime x & N \end{array} \right] \end{align*}$$

Note that
$$\begin{align*}\sum{(x_i - \bar{x})^2} = \sum{x_i^2} - N \bar{x}^2.\end{align*}$$

Looking at the lower right corner of the matrix, we have
$$\begin{align*}\frac{N}{N\sum{x_i^2} - \left(\sum{x_i}\right)^2}=
\frac{1}{\sum{x_i^2} - \frac{1}{N}\left(\sum{x_i}\right)^2} =       \frac{1}{\sum{x_i^2} - N \bar{x}^2} = \frac{1}{\sum{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}.\end{align*}$$
Multiplying by $\sigma^2$ gives the variance of the slope coefficient.

Comment: aargh, I was composing my answer when notification came :) The third equation has an error by the way.

Comment: Hm I clearly saw the earlier version with an error, but SE probably merged the revision. Now everything is ok. The error was that $\frac{1}{N}$ was besides the first term in the right hand side.

Comment: (+1) The first formula (for $X'X$) still contains typos... (but the rest of the analysis is correct).

Comment: @Charlie Thanks a lot! That was crystal clear! I won't not have a notebook by my side the next time I read stats...